# why does my while loop still run even though the expression equates to false

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm running the below code to print out numbers from 0 to 6. It works, but I can't figure out the reason why the code prints out the number 7. Why is the code still running even though number variable is now 7:

```
let number = 0;
while (number <= 6) {  
console.log(number);  
number = number + 1
}
```

I expected the code to only print up to 6 and then stop as any number above 6 would make the expression false

Comment: the code prints from 0 to 6

Comment: Are you running this in the console? You'd get the result of the last line but *this is not printed with `console.log()`*. It's just the REPL behaviour of the console.

Comment: Yes I am, I wasn't aware of this. Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks so much

Comment: :-) No need to feel like an idiot, but just take away the fact that the browser console is a tricky environment. Best to test code in the actual way you'll use it, rather than in the console.